# WEBGL_depth_texture precision is too low in iPhone

Tags: iphone, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

Recently, I attempted to make deferred renderer in WebGL for mobile browsers.
To make the deferred renderer, I need to render depth of the scene objects into texture once.
I know I can pack depth values into UBYTE RGBA texture when render the depth of the scene objects.

However, I somehow know iPhone is supporting WEBGL_depth_texture. So, now I tring to use that feature instead of using UBYTE RGBA.

That was works great when I debug the renderer in PC browser, but the depth texture was too low precision in iPhone browser.

This is these depth texture rendered into UBYTE RGBA from rendered depth texture.
Correct depth texture image(PC browser)
[image: PC]
Incorrect depth texture image(iPhone safari/chrome)
[image: iPhone]

And, emulator in Mac produced same image of PC browsers.

This is the code I used to fetch depth texture pixel and rendering into UBYTE RGBA texture.

```
    vec3 packUNorm24(const highp float value){
      const vec3 bitSh = vec3(256.0*256.0, 256.0, 1.0);
      const vec3 bitMsk = vec3(0.0, 1.0/256.0, 1.0/256.0);
      vec3 highp res = fract(value * bitSh);
      res -= res.xxy * bitMsk;
      return res;
     }

    vec3 packRanged24(const highp float value,const highp float minimum,const highp float maximum){
      return packUNorm24((value - minimum)/(maximum - minimum));
    }

    uniform sampler2D _depthBuffer;
    void main(void)
    {
      gl_FragColor.rgb = packRanged24(texture2D(_depthBuffer,uv).r,-1.,1.);
      gl_FragColor.a = 1.;
    }
```

Why these precision are too low?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the WEBGL_Depth_Texture spec (https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_depth_texture/) allows the implementation to decide between 16, 24 or 32 bit depth values.

While the precision might be too low for your needs, I don't think it's incorrect if the iPhone implementation is choosing 16-bit and the desktop implementation chooses 24-bit or greater.

> As per the OpenGL ES spec, there is no guarantee that the OpenGL ES implementation will use the texture type to determine how to store the depth texture internally. It may choose to downsample the 32-bit depth values to 16-bit or even 24-bit.

Comment: Is there any way to check how much bits are exactly used for these texture in the device?